# error handling for server errors with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, try-catch

I'm building a WebApp that creates a Google Document from a template and contains some user supplied data as well as data fetched from a 3rd party service. Since all of the Class (DriveApp, DocumentApp, etc) methods make a request to the Google server, a server glitch could cause a simple statement like `var doc = DocumentApp.openById(DOC_ID);` to fail, throw an error and stop the entire process dead in its tracks... without the user having any idea why everything appears to be "frozen" (unless he is savvy enough to check the console).

For that reason, would it be appropriate to wrap any/all functions using those methods in a `try/catch`? Something like:

```
function createDoc(DOC_ID) {
  try {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(DOC_ID);
    DriveApp.someMethod(...);
    doc.someOtherDocumentMethod();
    ...
  } catch(e) {
    handleServerError(e);
    return false;
  }
  return doc;
}
```

or is there a better way to handle any errors that may be out of the developer's control?

**EDIT**
Here's the request I send from my HTML page...

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = $('form').serializeObject(); 
    var gurl = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzmhaub3ojPARA-B-Y2uVC2BJZPaRvbgMwMTH9pd7R9aHuAD5M/exec';

    $.ajax({
      url: gurl,
      type : "GET", 
      data: obj,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success : function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
      },
      complete : function (xhr, status) {
        console.log("complete");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: The thing is, with Apps Script it's not just that calls to the API send requests to the server, as you can see in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), the entirety of the script gets run on Google servers. I'm sure they must handle their own server exceptions and manage those from the server itself. All you can do is prepare for the exceptions that can arise in your own code.

Comment: If you're calling from webapp, Why not just use `withFailureHandler()` to catch all errors?

Comment: Gotcha - I guess since i'm new at this i'm a little nervous about not knowing what i don't know. For example, pretend the string `#!` is not valid 4 a folder name & I didn't know this. Since I didn't even know about it (and it's odd enough 2 b missed in testing), I allow user to name a folder `my#!stuff` and `var cf = p.createFolder('my#!stuff');` throws an error and breaks the whole thing. To avoid that (until I know EVERYTHING about GAS), I am tempted to wrap everything in the try/catch so at least the app keeps going on errors caused by things i didn't know i didn't know. Is that hack-ish?

Comment: TheMaster's suggestion is good, [here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withFailureHandler(Function)) for `withFailureHandler()`

Comment: The documentation gives the example `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).someMethod()` to go in the HTML. I am POSTing user-input from my HTML to the GAS stuff. Is there any way to implement `withFailureHandler()` in doPost() or somewhere in the POST itself?

Comment: OR in my HTML, rather than doing a `$.post {}` to the deployed webapp page, can I call  `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).doPost(formVals);`? or something similar?

Comment: Show your html code and where is your html hosted? script.google.com or somewhere else? I'm sure `$.post().fail()` should be able to catch it. Or even `$.post().catch()`

Comment: @TheMaster - code posted. I'll have to play around with .fail()... will it capture the error message and the function/statement that caused it?

Comment: If you use `ajax`, use `error:` like `success:`

Comment: oh right, right, right. Duh - had been in front of the computer for a bit too long yesterday. Yes `.fail()` does catch the errors I was concerned about. The only issue is that it does not tell me which function caused the error. I can obviously figure it out with some digging but using try/catch, I can return the exact location of the error (along with the browser-generated error message).